# Cygwin Output problems

Tags: cygwin, output

I have this script `cut -d "|" -f 8,9,13,23 info.txt > result.txt`
When I open result.txt it looks like this:

```
 R S L T = R A C 2 6 8 | R A W T = r i c k a r d   a d a m   c e s a r   t w o   s i x   n i n e
```

When it should look like this:

```
 RSLT=RAC268|RAWT=rickard adam cesar two six nine
```

It works in the console, so my guess is that the problem is within the output operator.

Comment: What did you open result.txt in? What is the encoding of the text file? I've seen this when I've opened a UTF-8 text file in an editor that didn't know UTF-8.

Comment: How does the input look when opened in the same text editor?